# Is there a way to add today's date and 'file-2' to every row in a csv?

Tags: python, csv, file, date, export-to-csv

I have a csv file [without header]:

```
1,0,1,a
2,1,2,b
3,4,5,c
```

How do I convert it to a format with today's date and file-2 to each row?

```
1,0,1,a,2021-07-22,file2
2,1,2,b,2021-07-22,file2
3,4,5,c,2021-07-22,file2
```

Is this possible to do?
When I tried using csvwriter, I could append only to end.

```
with open("temp_csv.csv","a") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(','+date+',file2\n')
    print(writer)
```

Comment: use pandas...will be easier

Comment: The fact that it's a csv file is irrelevant in this case. Just open the file, read it line by line and append appropriately. You'll need to read the entire file into memory (or a scratch file if it's very big), then re-write the original file

Comment: Yes, how do we read it line by line? @AndyKnight

Comment: File objects are iterable, so `for line in input_file: ...` Note you'll have to append the data to each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the CSV module, then this works.

Your problem is you were trying to manipulate the csv inplace. Instead, you should read each line, process the line, and then write it to a new output csv file.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

todays_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

with open("in.csv","r") as fin, open("out.csv", 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in reader:
        line.append(todays_date)
        line.append("file2")
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Is this approach faster than pandas? Also, thanks a lot!

Comment: I am almost certain it wouldn't be. If I was doing this (simple case as above) I would just open the file and append the desired text to each line, then write the result to a new file (same as above without the use of csv). Although this is a csv file, you don't need to take advantage of the CSV module since the task you are doing is essentially independent of it being comma separated.

Comment: Got it, so it's basically for this type of use case. Thanks Chris!

Comment: No problem. I timed them - CSV method is faster for this use case (small csv), however, as the input csv file becomes much larger, pandas becomes faster. Having said that the margins are so small at small file size it is irrelevant!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the pandas library for this.

First, load your file as a dataframe `df` using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('temp_csv.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
```

then add the columns you want

```
df['date'] = ['2021-07-22' for i in range(len(df))]
df['file'] = ['file2' for i in range(len(df))]
```

Finally, save your csv

```
df.to_csv('temp_csv.csv', header=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, why are we putting index_col = 0? Is it necessary?

Comment: pandas adds another index column automatically otherwise. You can also remove `index_col=0` and just delete the additional column when saving (in `df.to_csv`)